# Leer CSV con miles de registros e insertar en base de datos por lotes

Tags: php, jquery, csv

Necesito leer e insertar un CSV de más de 100.000 registros. He conseguido que si es de un tamaño de filas pequeño me haga lo que quiero, pero cuando trabajo con el tamaño que os comento bloquea la página.

Mi idea era hacer esto mismo por lotes, por ejemplo de 500 en 500 registros. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? ¿Qué debo modificar?

Lo que tengo hasta el momento:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'procesarcsv.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: formdata,
            async: true,
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);                
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("error "+ errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Esta llamada ajax, llama a un .php. Me imagino que debería repetir esta llamada tantos lotes como sea posible

```
public function procesarcsv(){

        $batchsize = 10;
        $handle = fopen("/carpeta/micsv.csv","r");

        for ($i=0; $i < $batchsize; $i++) {     

            $line = fgetcsv($handle);    
            $col1 = $line[0];
            $col2 = $line[1];
            $col3 = $line[2];
            $col4 = $line[3];
            $col5 = $line[4];
            $col6 = $line[5];
            $col7 = $line[6];
            $json = "'$col1', '$col2', '$col3', '$col4', '$col5', '$col6', '$col7'";
            echo "JSON = ". $json . "<br>";
            $this->insertIntoDDBB($json); //va insertando cada línea en la bbdd

        }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo leer e insertar por lotes un CSV con miles de registros?

Comment: No es que te bloquea la pagina. Es que es un proceso muy largo y va a tardar. Si lo dejas suficiente tiempo, en algun momento va a terminar. Ahora que nos sacamos ese tema de encima, hay muchas formas de solucionar esto. probaste eso que dijiste de hacer la llamada una y otra vez?

Comment: Como dijo @gbianchi, hay muchas solucione. Para mi, si vas a consumir archivos grandes todo el tiempo, por que no permitir que el usuario suba el archivo (de preferencia compreso) y lo procesas en el servidor. Si tu servidor esta en AWS puedes salvar la info en s3. Usa los SDKs que tienen. Ahi hay soporte para subir archivos realmente grandes. Suerte.

Comment: Otra forma, podrias retornar 202 Accepted sin poner exit() or die()  desde tu archivo PHP y seguir procesando tu archivo.  En tu pagina web, con jquery, y basado en la respuesta mostrar una nota que se esta procesando.  Una vez q termine de ejecutarse, puedes mandar un email con el resultado. Si quieres llegar un poco mas lejos, hasta podrias retornar la respuesta a travez de Web sockets. suerte.

Comment: o usar un worker. En general esta clase de procesos no se hace on line. Y si es online, necesitas una manera de avisarle a tu UI que algo esta pasando...

Answer (score 0):

La manera más básica de implementarlo es hacer que el programa lea las primeras N filas "en falso", sólo para ir avanzando el puntero del archivo. Entonces tenemos que manejar 3 variables:

- Variable `$offset`: cuántas filas saltarme
- Variable `$batchsize`: cuántas filas procesar
- Variable `$ultima_fila`: la última fila a leer, se infiere de las otras dos.

Y 3 estados:

- Estado "omito la línea" cuando no he alcanzado el `$offset`
- Estado "proceso la línea" cuando ya alcancé el $offset`y he procesado menos de`$batchsize`
- Estado "salgo del bucle" cuando ya alcancé `$ultima_fila`

Digamos que tu clase tiene un método `procesaFila` en donde genera la variable `$json`, para simplificar el ejemplo.

```
public function procesarcsv($offset = 0, $batchsize = 10){
  $position=0;
  $ultima_fila = $offset + $batchsize;

  $handle = fopen("/carpeta/micsv.csv","r");
  while( ($line = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE ) {
     if($position <= $offset) {
       continue; // las primeras N iteraciones nos saltamos el resto
     }
     $json = $this->procesaFila($line);
     echo "JSON = ". $json . "<br>";
     $this->insertIntoDDBB($json);
     $position++;
     if($position >= $ultima_fila ) {
       break; // si ya pasamos el límite 
     }
  } 
  fclose($handle);
}
```

El método no es muy eficiente. Voy a probar algo mejor y edito la respuesta.

**Edit: Aquí una manera más eficiente**

Voy a usar comandos de linux. Si estás en windows esta alternativa no te va a servir directamente.

Básicamente, en linux podemos tomar un archivo de 100.000 filas y obtener las filas 10000 a 10100 haciendo

```
head -10100 archivo.csv | tail -100
```

Básicamente: toma las primeras 10100 líneas y pásaselas a tail, que leerá sólo las 100 últimas.

Entonces, usando el mismo footprint anterior

```
public function procesarcsv($offset = 0, $batchsize = 10){
  $position=0;
  $ultima_fila = $offset + $batchsize;

  $cmd = sprintf('head -%s /carpeta/micsv.csv | tail -%s', $ultima_fila, $batchsize);

  $descriptorspec = [
    0 => ['pipe', 'r'], // stdin
    1 => ['pipe', 'w'], // stdout
    2 => ['pipe', 'w'], // stderr
  ];

  $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

  if (is_resource($process)) {
      while ($s = fgets($pipes[1])) {
        $line = str_getcsv($s);
        $json = $this->procesaFila($line);
        echo "JSON = ". $json . "<br>";
        $this->insertIntoDDBB($json);
      }
  }
  fclose($pipes[0]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);
  fclose($pipes[2]);
  proc_close($process);
}
```